# Web API (.NET Framework) Azure AD Authentication always returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

My scenario is like I've to deploy the Web API(.NET Framework) in Azure Web App and all the requests should go via Azure AD Authentication. I googled and found similar case provided by Microsoft. I have followed the below sample provided by Microsoft and when I tested this code in machine it is working fine.

[Native client to Web API to Web API.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof)

In my case, I am able to generate the OAuth2 token but the problem is I'm always getting 401 Unauthorized error. I have followed many blogs but not able to figure out what is causing the problem. Any help is really appreciated.

Here my code is:

Startup.cs

```
    public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"] }
            });
    }
```

Controller.cs

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            using (sqldbEntities entities = new sqldbEntities())
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GetMethod"]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log4net.log.Error(string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorGetData"], ex.Message));
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Generating the token in two ways:
**Method 1)** From another ASP.NET application

```
private static AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        Uri redirectUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"]);

        private static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
        private static string todoListResourceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["todo:TodoListResourceId"];            

protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));
            TextBox1.Text = result.AccessToken;
        }
```

**Method 2)** From Postman
URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/myad.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token

Method: POST

Body:
grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=89479d4f-aaaa-4ebf-80f2-13e423431bfb&client_secret=hZ_8Ls1EmFarH_lPn4=aaaa-k8TJ_&redirect_uri=https://NAClient-OBO/&code=AQABAAIAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8KZRKktzMuxXp0hM6k1B__lWQrxaikd6wwrYrKZ470UAdr4g1GqAPWja6JgpqsDtLefE23vW80qP7xgVodury28LkGLzL1Mbq0auUeiBaaaa-oCZf11o5EsaSVRVlke6FMkbIn_ppA_GsEBhIAEjxHXXjkrIcp-e4g0G5t9prme4IZ0Sg2_L4MvN6TAyr-nEPGDlnWZLBkRvu8Izsm3RiI_cnneCi1xonZaKBSlsgONIwpgN1bOaz16OVW2uu5lTiz206CSrJtzWeKkitPNUx2Gnn-RnZcCUVDyLxK-eJy8o_ggn_iu7F7kdjKj-b70Gfp5BPYx6fxB4Zyw8tpnWzVkLG7IbLGx9di112u-UGgVSBfWQiO5w3a4Mx2KdDcUihMlVW_mgBUdQi4160AKq1Id9ZcpJEKCT11KWwkO25_q7huCxJ_6-mEU4ADCGjj8hDOtRLGNeZMwhB13rYTN7qGQMmpX491RoldCfpfevva16DhQl5VHbIqspknkK1pFHvh90J47DSg0VihQOIQp1FZ7EgAA&resource=89479d4f-aaaa-4ebf-80f2-13e423431bfb

Please help.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Thanks Jim. It helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following steps to implement it

1. Configure Azure AD for your web API. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview)

   a. Create Azure AD web api application

   b.  [Expose  API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)
    [image]
2. [Create client application to access the web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)
3. Configure code

   - web api

     a. Startup.cs

     ```
      public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
     {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = "<your tenant id>",
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = new[] { "your web api application app id url", "your web api application app id" }
                },
            }) ;;
     }
     ```

     b. Controller

     ```
     [Authorize]
     [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
     public class ValuesController : ApiController
     {
     // GET api/values
     public IEnumerable<string> Get()
     {
      return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
     }
     }
     ```
   - client application. I use console application to call api

   ```
   var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenat id>";
         AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
         var uri = "< your redirect url>";
         var clientId = "< your client application app id>";
         var resource = "<your web api application app id url or your web api application app id>";
        var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(uri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)).Result;

         using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
         {

             httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

             var response = httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44345/api/values").Result;
             Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
             Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

         }
   ```

   [image]